# Web audio api - LFO on buffer pitch

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to add an lfo the a buffer sounds playbackrate value, similar to how you would for an oscillator's frequency?

I've tried creating an oscillator node, setting the frequency value to 2, connecting it to a gain node, setting the gain value to 1000 and then connecting the gain node to the buffer sound's playbackrate but to no effect.

My code:

```
function Sound(path) {
    var that = this;
    that.buffer = null;
    that.path = path
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', that.path, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function() {
    ac.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
      that.buffer = buffer;
    });
  }
  request.send();
}

Sound.prototype.play = function(a,b) {
        var lfo = ac.createOscillator();
        lfo.frequency.value = 0.5
        var lfoAmp = ac.createGain();
        lfoAmp.gain.value = 1000
        var gain = ac.createGain();
        gain.gain.value = a;
        var playSound = ac.createBufferSource();
        playSound.playbackRate.value = b;
        lfo.connect(lfoAmp);
        lfoAmp.connect(playSound.playbackRate);
        playSound.buffer = this.buffer;
        playSound.loop = true;
        playSound.connect(gain);
        gain.connect(ac.destination);
        lfo.start(0);
        playSound.start(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a lot of context from your example that makes it hard to debug (e.g. what is the b parameter?)  If you can link to a live example, I can look in more detail.

It is absolutely possible to drive playback rate with an LFO in roughly the way you describe - but an oscillator's output is going to vary between [-1,1], so your lfoAmp's output is going to vary between [-1000,1000].  That will then get summed with the playsound.playbackRate, so it will vary between [-1000+b, 1000+b].  That's a BIG multiplier - in fact, current implementations clamp the playbackRate to something like [0,4] (not positive about exact range - see https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/391#issuecomment-61673716.)

1) you probably want to vary playbackRate between [0.5,2] or something like that; aliasing and harmonics make stretching more than pretty ugly-sounding.

2) it's probably a lot easier, and certainly more musical, to vary .detune, rather than .playbackRate.  Vary it by [-1200,1200] for a one-octave-up, one-octave-down shift.

(In fact, playbackRate is currently specified as k-rate, which would damage this scenario a bit, but there's a bug on it: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/55.)